# Check validity of UMLS licence in UmlsDictionaryLookupAnnotator

Tags: ctakes

In UmlsDictionaryLookupAnnotator there is a function isValidUMLSUser having four parameters. In which two of them are username and pass which i have entered correctly but other two are license code and url. Can anyone help me out to find the correct URL if they have used up for validating user.

Answer (score 0):

URL is

```
https://uts-ws.nlm.nih.gov/restful/isValidUMLSUser?user=gprakhar&password=XXXXXXXXX&licenseCode=NLM-999915557
```

Just so you know this URL is part of UMLS REST API for user validation.

BTW why exactly do you need need to call 'isValidUMLSUser' function ?

I ask since it is automatically called whenever a Analysis Engine uses UMLS dictionary components.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's been a long time, but while rereading this it hit me.. you would obviously need to supply License info for User authentication. Since UMLS dict is not free for all countries.